# How to display new lines in textarea?

Tags: php, textarea

I'm adding text to MySQL database from textarea. 
All newlines are converted to \r\n
I'm able to diplay new lines correcly in html by using below scipt:

```
function solver_nl2br($e){
  $output = str_replace("\\r\\n", "<br/>", $e);
  return $output;
}
```

But when I'm trying to edit text in textarea all I can see is `\r\n` instead of new lines.

What function I can use to display new lines instead of new line characters in textarea?

Comment: Just to explain properly: Above function works and converts new line characters into <br/> but that works only if text is as plain html. That doesn't work if you put text in textarea. Instead new lines you will see <br/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use native function `nl2br()`.  It will catch more cases: (\r\n, \n\r, \n and \r).  FYI: There are also constants for new lines PHP_EOL.  You want your code to run well on Windows or Linux when possible.

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
  $output = nl2br(htmlenitites($e));
```

Comment: nl2br doesn't work when you escape data saved in MySQL. I already tried that. My fuction works for plain text in html but doesn't when text is in textarea.

Comment: str_replace('<br />', PHP_EOL, $yourContent);

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$output = str_replace("\\r\\n", "\n", $e);
```